# How to simulate reference of a type with C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, reflection

I want to wrap a reference of a type with a class to add other functionality to it, something like below, but I don't want to force the use of a function or operator to access base type methods.

```
class A {
    private:
        int fX;
    public:
        void SetSomething(int x){ fX = x; }
        int GetSomething() { return fX; }
};

template<typename T>
class Ref {
    private:
        T& fRef;
    public:
        Ref(T &ref) : fRef(ref) {}
        inline operator T&() { return fRef; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    Ref<A> ref(a);
    ref.SetSomething(100);
    return 0;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8x8aehb8e

Is possible to implement this kind of template ?

Comment: `operator ->` (`ref->SetSomething(100);`)?

Comment: There is always `std::reference_wrapper` to consider. @Jarod42: `std::optional` uses `operator*()`.

Comment: How about you derive from `A` and add your functionality that way?

Comment: It's not possible because this type must pass by reference to containers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, transparent proxies are not currently possible in C++. You can either inherit from the type, implement `operator->` or recreate the whole interface. I usually rewrite the whole interface in the reference type.